# How do I pass a parameter to views and access all objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm using the slug as the access point for the url.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/blah/ -> blah is the slug.
```

This is my url code.

```
 url(r'^category/(?P<category>[A-Za-z]\w*)/$', individual_category),
```

this is my views

```
def individual_category(request, category): 

    pro =  get_object_or_404(Product, username= category) -> (This doesnt seem to work ))
    return render_to_response('individual_category.html', {'obs':pro})
```

This is my tempalte

```
<html>
<body>
<p> The list of products are </p>
<b>{{category}}</b>

{% for items in obs %}

    <li>{{items.category}}</li>
    <li>{{items.title}}</li>
    <img src = "/images/{{items.image}}"</li>   

    <br>
    <br>

{% endfor %}



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `This doesnt seem to work`... Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Post your Product model please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand your models definition, you are making the wrong query:

```
pro =  get_object_or_404(Product, username= category) -> (This doesnt seem to work ))
```

You are trying to select a product where it's username is equal to category. Now i don't know if your model `Product` has a field `username` (i doubt it), but my guess is that you need to filter on the `category` field.

However `get_object_or_404` only selects 1 object and seeing your template, this isn't what you want.

I think you better use:

```
pro = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
```

If category is a model you need to get the object from your database first, therefore the `get_object_or_404` method would be appropriate.